# Firefox addon to fix layout automatically in address bar

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-layout, firefox-extensions

As I'm using EN/RU double keyboard layout configuration, there's a lot of situations, when I spell something to address bar in English, while current keyboard layout is set for Russian, and vice versa. It would be useful to see a guess, which offers "translayouted" text in such cases. Is there an addon for Firefox to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard about Firefox add-on, but there are some system-dependent tools for that:

- [X Neural Switcher](http://xneur.ru/) aka `xneur` (free / libre) for X.org
- [Punto Switcher](http://punto.yandex.ru/) (freeware for personal use) for MS Windows and OS X
- [Keyboard Ninja](http://www.keyboard-ninja.com/) (freeware) for MS Windows
- [Key Switcher](http://www.keyswitcher.com/) (freeware for personal use) for MS Windows

All of them can switch keyboard layout on the fly, but if it annoys you, you can disable autoswitch and translate `qwerty` to `йцукен` and vice versa by pressing a hotkey.

Also Google search detects wrong layout in most cases, so you can set ‘I’m feeling lucky’ as default search engine, then something like `дутефюкг` will lead you to http://lenta.ru/.